# C# IAttachmentExecute

Tags: c#

Im trying to use the [IAttachmentExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776297%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface in my C# application. (Using .NET4 and VS2010).
MSDN says it is in `Shdocvw.dll` (and its members says that `IAttachmentExecute` is specified in `Shobjidl.h / Shobjidl.idl` which leads me to a `73db1241-1e85-4581-8e4f-a81e1d0f8c57` GUID.)

When I add a reference to this DLL in VS I get the generated `SHDocVw`-Namespace, but it does not contain this interface.

Every other attempt with `System.Type.GetTypeFromCLSID` and `System.Activator.CreateInstance` or `System.Activator.CreateComInstanceFrom` fails with the message that there is no type with that GUID.

How can I use that interface?
(Dont think there are alternatives.)

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
*Generated interface definition with*:
`MIDL.exe` msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680078.aspx
`Tlbimp.exe` msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx

**Edit2**:
*Independent from interface def.:*
Tries with `CoCreateInstance` fail with `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`, so how could I make my program find `IAttachmentExecute`. *Or am I wrong with my problem and simply miss the solution / my mistake?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what I just investigated, here's the blog post: http://joco.name/2010/12/22/windows-antivirus-api-in-net-and-a-com-interop-crash-course/

Comment: Excellent! (That ComImport replacing CreateInstance is epic)