# Virus scanning for uploaded files on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Does Microsoft offer the service of having a virus or malware scan on files uploaded via http on Azure Websites?

If not, does anybody know whether this is in the pipeline?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862992/can-a-worker-role-process-call-antimalware-for-azure-cloud-services-programmatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also check-out [MetaScan Online](https://www.metascan-online.com/public-api%20#!/):
https://www.metascan-online.com/public-api%20#!/

As long as you don't exceed 25 files per hour, its free, and it uses over 40 AV / Anti-Malware Scanning engines together.

This should have a very good chance of finding any potential malicious files.

There is also a REST API to make the checks easy.

Comment: We found Metadefender but it doesn't fit. Adding for others to know. - Seems that the Cloud API scan is quick but the CDR takes about a minute and it is limited per day upload of files so it is not fit.

As per Metadefender Core seems it is very costly for it's about 3000$ annually for 8 engines with 83% rate of virus discovery and it needs Azure VM that costs additional 160$ at least(checked for 4 CPU cores and not 8)

Actively looking for other solution

Answer (score 4):

No there is no currently such service for **Azure Web Sites**. And to my knowledge there is nothing in the pipeline.

There is Microsoft Antimalware for IaaS and PaaS services, but still there is no API to explicitly scan uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've seen other implement is to host their site on PaaS or IaaS and use something like http://www.clamav.net/ (see https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq for more info).

You could possibly integrate with service like VirusTotal API: https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/